# How to Count Rows from two Tables with one Command in MySQL

Tags: mysql

i want to count 2 tables from diferent table, im select the `date` then i group it.

here what i try

```
SELECT 
(SELECT date(date), COUNT(sh_sh) FROM sh_url GROUP BY date(date)) AS URLs, 
(SELECT date(date), COUNT(ip) FROM tracking GROUP BY date(date)) AS IP 
FROM dual
```

but i get error

> ## 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

is that posible to do it in one command?

the output should be like this

```
date(url)    count(sh_sh)    date(ip)    count(ip)
---------    ------------    ----------  ----------
2018-04-25   123             2018-04-25  123123
2018-04-26   456             2018-04-26  321
2018-04-27   789             2018-04-27  3125
```

Comment: Use SQL Joins : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: You are creating a derived column from a subquery. When you do that, you can't stick 2 columns in 1 column. That's why it tells you that operand should contain 1 column. You can't select two columns (`date` and `COUNT(ip)`) into `IP`. Get it? You can rewrite this query using a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would phrase your problems using a join of two subqueries:

```
SELECT
    t1.date,
    t1.url_cnt,
    COALESCE(t2.ip_cnt, 0) AS ip_cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT date, COUNT(*) url_cnt
    FROM sh_url
    GROUP BY date
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT date, COUNT(*) ip_cnt
    FROM tracking
    GROUP BY date
) t2
    ON t1.date = t2.date;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use a subquery as a value, it can only return one row and one column. You need to use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT urls.date, urls.count AS sh_count, ip.count AS ip_count
FROM (SELECT date(date) AS date, COUNT(*) AS count FROM sh_url GROUP BY date(date)) AS urls
JOIN (SELECT date(date) AS date, COUNT(*) AS count FROM tracking GROUP BY date(date)) AS ip
ON urls.date = ip.date
```