# How to Show Data From Different Table and Date to Chart

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-visualization

i want to showing my data from database to chart, here im using google chart.

the problem is, when i count and join the table, when the **date** from two table is different the data is not show up.

for example i have data like this.

table1

```
date(table1)    sh_sh  
---------    ------------ 
2018-04-25   data1
2018-04-26   data2
2018-04-27   data3
```

table2

```
date(table2)    ip  
---------    ------------ 
2018-04-28   data1
2018-04-25   data2
2018-04-24   data3
```

and i run code like this, i got this code from  [my question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50038370/how-to-count-rows-from-two-tables-with-one-command-in-mysql)

```
SELECT urls.date, urls.count AS sh_count, ip.count AS ip_count FROM
(SELECT date(date) AS date, COUNT(*) AS count FROM table1 GROUP BY date(date)) AS urls JOIN
(SELECT date(date) AS date, COUNT(*) AS count FROM table2 GROUP BY date(date)) AS ip ON urls.date = ip.date
```

the output is

```
date(url)    count(sh_sh)    count(ip)
---------    ------------    ----------
2018-04-25   1               1
```

date **24,26,27,28** not show up cause different date.

what i have to do, to show up the data with different **table** and **date**.

and when there's no data i want to print **0**.

here my chart script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Urls', 'Clicks'],
    <?php
    while ($areacharts = $areachart->fetch()) { 
    echo "['".$areacharts['date']."',".$areacharts['sh_count'].",".$areacharts['ip_count']."],";
    } ?>
    ]);
    var options = {
              hAxis: {title: 'Date',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
              vAxis: {minValue: 0}
            };
    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('summary_chart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    $(window).resize(function(){
      drawChart();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: try full join and use case syntax in select

Comment: @WhiteHat i mean one chart but with 2 diferent data, so i can compare it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
SELECT
    a.`date`,
    sum(a.sh_sh_cnt) as sh_sh_cnt,
    sum(a.ip_cnt) as ip_cnt
FROM(SELECT
        `date`,
        count(*) as sh_sh_cnt,
        sum(0) as ip_cnt
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY `date`

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        `date`,
        sum(0) as sh_sh_cnt,
        count(*) as ip_cnt
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY `date`) a
GROUP BY a.`date`
```

It isn't very pretty, but it should work.

With the same data you have, this should return:

```
date        sh_sh_cnt  ip_cnt
----        ---------  ------
2018-04-24  0          1
2018-04-25  1          1
2018-04-26  1          0
2018-04-27  1          0
2018-04-28  0          1
```

Also, please don't name your date field "date". It's a reserved word... You don't want to use reserved words for field names! It'll work, don't get me wrong, but it's very, very bad practice!

Comment: woah, thanks bro, u save my brain... ill renamed it.

Answer (score 1):

use `UNION ALL` to join the two results,
then group on date again,
something like this...

```
SELECT
  a.date AS date,
  SUM(a.count) AS count
FROM (
  SELECT date(date) AS date, COUNT(*) AS count FROM sh_url GROUP BY date(date)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date(date) AS date, COUNT(*) AS count FROM tracking GROUP BY date(date)
) a
GROUP BY
  a.date
```

Comment: that will join all result. i want it diferent so i can make two bar chart, bar chart for `sh_url` and bar for `tracking`

Comment: well if thats the case, would you mind adding the expected result in your question please? WhiteHat's answer made sense to me, I was about to answer the same... If that's not what you want, I'm not sure what to answer you!

Comment: see my answer, I think I understood what you are looking for.